# UIHint - Disable Mvc.TemplateNotResolved for project or solution

Tags: c#, resharper, rider, asp.net-mvc-uihint

On Rider and Visual Studio + ReSharper, `UIHint` attributes that cannot be resolved by IDE are highlighted as red. For example:

[image]

There are a few solution on how to bypass the warning:

- Either configure severity of the Inspection in the IDE (default is Error)
- Or, disable Error by inline comment: `// ReSharper disable once Mvc.TemplateNotResolved`

However, I would like to set that inspection severity to None, but for a project or solution. Is it possible?

I tried to use .editorconfig, but with no success.

I'm using JetBrains Rider, but looking for the solution for both Rider and Visual Studio w/ ReSharper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add the following node to the team-shared dotSettings file (`*.sln.DotSettings`):

`<s:String x:Key="/Default/CodeInspection/Highlighting/InspectionSeverities/=Mvc_002ETemplateNotResolved/@EntryIndexedValue">HINT</s:String>`